# Finding error of Newton's method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

So we have the following question given for homework. For the first part, I got that this would not converge quadratically because f(2)=0 and f'(2)=0. Is that correct?

For the second bit, I used ei= |r-guess at i| and substituted that for e(i+1) and ei. I simplified this to
$ 1+ f(xi)/[(2-xi)*f'(xi)]$ as i goes to infinity.

What do I do from here.
[image]

Comment: You can directly compute (and considerably simplify) $\frac{x_{i+1}-2}{x_i - 2}$.

Comment: how so? I figured since we know this is linearly convergent, I could say this error would go to 0. Is there anything else?

Comment: The limit you're computing is not the limit of the error; it's the limit of the ratio of the consecutive errors.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: Hi! Please use Mathjax to typeset your mathematics, so that content can be found by the search engine. E.g., `$e_i$` gives $e_i$, `$f(x) = x^4-7x^3$` gives $f(x) = x^4-7x^3$, `$\lim_{i\to\infty} e_{i+1}/e_i$` gives $\lim_{i\to\infty} e_{i+1}/e_i$, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I found after searching for a whole
[image]